# Conditional Homepage for logged in user

Tags: plugins, functions, theme-development

I want to change the home page url of wordpress site to another url when the user is logged in and have a specific role. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider to be the home page?

Do you want to change what is answering on the `/` url on your website?

If so, I think that you can use the `init` hook and use [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function to send your user wherever you want based on the result of [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) result.

Something like that.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    if ($user = wp_get_current_user()) {
        if (in_array('my-custom-role', $user->roles)) {
            wp_redirect('/my-custom-url');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `init` can be too late for this, I think `template_redirect` is the recommended hook for redirection.

Comment: As far as I can see it (just put both actions in a plugin)  `init` has been called before `template_redirect`, but you're right that the WP code reference shows to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this absolutely is possible. There are a couple of steps that you would need to take to get this working;

1. Check that the user is currently on the front page, you can use the [`is_front_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) function for this, you may need to use [`is_home`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) or even both depending on your configuration and requirements.
2. Check that the user is currently logged in, you can use the [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function to check that they are.
3. Get the user roles. These can be retrieved from the object returned by [`wp_get_current_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)
4. Check that the user has the expected role.
5. Redirect. You should use [`wp_safe_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) for this as it would ensure that the url you are redirecting to is one that belongs to your site.

This is then called on the `init` hook as that ensures some of the methods and data will be available, such as the current user, and allow the redirect to happen as soon as possible.

A full example may look like the following:

```php
function redirect_from_front_page() {
    $redirect_url  = '/example/url'; // Change this to the path or url you wish to redirect to.
    $expected_role = 'custom-role'; // Change this to the role you would like to redirect based on.
    
    /**
     * Check that the user is on the front page
     * before continuing.
     */
    if( ! is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the user is logged in.
     */
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the currect user roles.
     */
    $user  = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $user->roles;
    
    /**
     * If the user has a role that matches the expected role
     * redirect to the given page.
     */
    if ( in_array( $expected_role, $roles ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'redirect_from_front_page' );
```